# Convert php arrays with the new syntax

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I looking for a way (regex, snippet ,plugin etc) to convert the old arrays with the new php syntax with sublimeText.

```
// Old synthax
$var = array(
   'foo' => 'bar' 
);

// New synthax
$var = [
   'foo' => 'bar'
];
```

someone has an idea ?

Comment: @Kafin You should change your edit into an answer and accept it.

Comment: I don't think new users can accept their own answers yet can they?

Comment: Yes i can, but in two days :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a script that does the job perfectly !

https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter

Answer (score 5):

I found out that it is also possible to do this with the php codesniffer: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

```
phpcbf src/ --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.Arrays.DisallowLongArraySyntax
```

In this example you have to replace src/ with the folder containing the scripts. Alternatively you can provide a file name.

Comment: If you use PhpStorm, It will automatically convert it to new format if the rule is given in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I created my own. Maybe not pretty, but it does do the job I want. If you do not like tab, change \t in indent function to 2 or 4 spaces.

```
    function loopArray(array $array, $loopcount = 0) {

        $returnString = ($loopcount == 0) ? "[\n" : "";

        $tabKey = indent($loopcount + 2);
        $tabValue = indent($loopcount + 3);

        $lastKey = array_key_last($array);

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

            $totalChildren = count($array[$key]);

            $returnString .= $tabKey . '"' . $key . '" => ';

            if ($totalChildren == 0) $returnString .= '[]';
            if ($totalChildren > 0 && is_array($array[$key])) $returnString .= '[' . "\n";

            if (is_array($value)) {

                $returnString .= loopArray($value, $loopcount + 1);
            } else {

                if ($totalChildren == 1) $returnString .=  '"' . $value . '"';
                if ($totalChildren > 1)  $returnString .=  $tabValue . '"' . $value . '"'  . ",\n";
            }

            $returnString .= ($lastKey == $key) ? "\n" . indent($loopcount+1) . "]" : ",\n";
        }

        return $returnString;
    }

    function indent($amount) {

        return str_repeat("\t", $amount);
    }

/** use function below only prior to php 7.3 */

    function array_key_last(array $array) {

        $key = NULL;

        if ( is_array( $array ) ) {

            end( $array );
            $key = key( $array );
        }

        return $key;
    }
```